# Voltage level difference when using an external power supply

Tags: voltage-regulator, grounding

I'm making up an interface board for an old computer system (an Oric Atmos), but I have pretty basic electronic experience.

Version 1 of my board works fine.  It converts the Oric's rather curious CMOS RGB output to a SCART compatible output, powered from the machine's expansion port.

Version 2 runs from an external 5v supply which then runs through a DC-DC Booster to supply the Oric, replacing it's original PSU.  In this configuration the machine fails to boot once the board is connected to the RGB socket of the Oric.

I've managed to trace the problem, but I don't know how to fix it.  The Oric uses an LM7905 internally rather than a LM7805.  As a result, rather than pulling Vcc down, it pulls the earth up.  On my circuit, the signal ground from the RGB port is then made common with the supply earth and everything stops working.  The Oric is basically running at +7.5/+2.5v in relation to my SCART converter.  This wasn't a problem previously because it was powered directly from the Oric's expansion port.

How can I hook up the RGB output to the SCART converter when their earths are on different levels?  I assume that I need to somehow use the input RGB signals in reference to their signal ground, but not common that ground with the rest of the converters circuitry.  I've probably missed something pretty basic as this has to be a common occurrence.

[image: Block diagram]

Comment: Why taint this question by mentioning arduinos? Also: an image says more than N words, so annotated schematics are useful to have an idea what is going on and you talk about.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Because it's relevant to my long term goals.  Solving the problem for 3 pins may not be the same as solving it for 24+ pins.  I don't actually have circuit schematics, but it's based on the description [here](http://www.defence-force.org/computing/oric/hardware/video/index.htm) and the picture at the bottom is the V1 of my board.  I will try to block diagram this problem to make it clearer.

Comment: I got lost in all the hand waving 1/3 of the way thru this question.  Without a diagram, all we can do is close this question.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: Diagram added, hand waving removed, more direct question added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, draw diagrams with logical flow left to right.  It was confusing at first since your DC-DC booster and 5 V buck regulator are shown backwards, and in/out is not labeled.

The basic problem seems to be that this Oric thing's power supply reference and signal ground are not the same.  The simplest way to solve this within your diagram is to provide the Oric with its own isolated supply.  Then it can float arbitrarily, which allows you to pick any one of its lines and tie that to your ground.  You would pick the signal ground on the expansion port.

You could just get a separate 7.5 V power supply for the Oric and be done with it.  If you really need to create the 7.5 V from the 5 V supply for some reason, then that converter needs to provide isolation.  You could do this with a flyback converter, for example, since those are inherently isolated via the transformer.  There are also many off the shelf DC-DC isolated modules available.  7.5 V is a rather unusual output voltage, buy maybe you can find one if you look around.

Comment: Noted about the logical flow. I've been having machine problems, so it was a race against time and I wasn't really thinking.

Comment: Hit enter by accident... So having two separate power supplies off the mains won't tie the grounds together?  If that's the case then your solution is perfect.  The 7.5 V supply is to reduce heat in the (35 year old) machine. It's supposed to run at 9 V, but the LM7905 is good down to about 7 V or as high as 30 V.

Comment: I just jury rigged this configuration with two discreet power adapters and the result can be seen [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bsei40mcp1jr90y/2016-03-02%2008.42.06.jpg?dl=0). Answer proved and accepted. Thank you @OlinLathrop.